# do query in another query, if another query not exists return 0 and compare value between 2 query

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched over and over but still can't write a correct query that actually work ! :|

I write this one and it seems ok but it's dosen't worked...

```
select 
  s.surf_id, 
  s.surf_dailyuser, 
  s.surf_url, 
  s.surf_cpc, 
  (if exists(
   select surfed_count from `surfed` where s.surf_id = surfed_site and surfed_date = 'today'
  ) then select surfed_count as surfedcount;
   else select 0 as surfedcount; end if
  )
  from `surfs` s where s.surf_status = 1 and surfedcount < s.surf_dailyuser order by s.surf_rand limit 1
```

any suggestion will be a big help :)

tables are like this

## surfs

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `surfs` (
  `surf_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surf_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surf_title` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `surf_url` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `surf_dailyuser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surf_cpc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surf_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surf_date` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## surfed

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `surfed` (
  `surfed_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surfed_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surfed_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surfed_site` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surfed_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `surfed_date` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statement as below

```
select 
  s.surf_id, 
  s.surf_dailyuser, 
  s.surf_url, 
  s.surf_cpc, 
  CASE WHEN 
   (select surfed_count from `surfed` where s.surf_id = surfed_site and surfed_date = 'today') = 1 then (select surfed_count as surfedcount)

  ELSE 0 END AS surfedcount
  from `surfs` s where s.surf_status = 1 and surfedcount < s.surf_dailyuser order by s.surf_rand limit 1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for responding, but i face with this error : "Reference 'surfedcount' not supported (forward reference in item list)"...when i change this part "...then (select surfed_count as surfedcount)..." to "...then (select surfed_count)...", i face with this error : "Unknown column 'surfed_count' in 'field list'...", but surfed_count clumn exsists ! i even try to reselect surfed_count after using THEN but its not worked too...

Comment: You cant use `surfedcount` because you have not selected sarfed table,
surfedcount is a field of sarfed table,
if you can create relationship with these two table like 'inner join' , then you can use this field

so create primary key and foring key and join two tables

Comment: thanks for suggestion, the problem is `surfed` table always will be change, so there is no way that i can join two table together, so i need to query separately, then compare result....

Comment: Can you add Primary key of surfs  as a foring key to the surfed table.
Then you can join. it is no prob whether surfed will change always